# Почему if...else не работает?

Tags: javascript

Вот код, в котором `else` не работает, он стоит по стандарту, то есть когда товар даже найден, то все равно выполняется то, что прописано в `else`, что не так?

```
  products.forEach(function(e) { 
    if(e.id ==  id) {
     document.getElementById('product-name').innerHTML = e.name;
     document.getElementById('product-miniAbout').innerHTML = e.miniAbout;
     document.getElementById('product-about').innerHTML = e.about;
     document.getElementById('product-category').innerHTML = e.category;
     document.getElementById('product-id').innerHTML = e.id;
     document.getElementById('product-bigPicture').innerHTML = '<img src="'+ e.img +'" style="max-height: 450px;" alt="'+ e.miniAbout +'">';
     document.getElementById('product-picture').innerHTML = '<img src="'+ e.img +'" alt="'+ e.miniAbout +'">';
     document.getElementById('product-price').innerHTML = e.price + ' Грн.';
    } else {
      document.getElementById('product-bigPicture').innerHTML = '<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/38/awhCbhLqRceCdjcPQUnn_IMG_0249.jpg?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&w=1080&fit=max&s=9c2c8df6c036962d2ba24fd6af421a40" style="max-height: 450px;">';
      document.getElementById('product-about').innerHTML = 'Товар не найден!';
      document.getElementById('product-product').innerHTML = '<b>Cheap Shopping</b>';
      document.getElementById('delivery').innerHTML = '<b>Cheap Shopping</b>';
    }
    return;
    });
```

Comment: Если убрать условие else то все работает, а когда добавляю else что бы не показывать пустые товары, то товары которые не пустые перестают показываться и пишет что товар не найден

Comment: А можете предоставить html и сам мам массив данных?

Comment: говорите про товары во множественном числе, а в коде завязываетесь на `getElementById`. ID должен быть уникален.

Comment: В данном случае, именно страница на которой выводиться конкретный 1 товар по id

Comment: `var found=false; if(e.id==id) { ваши действия когда найдено; found=true; }  ПОСЛЕ ЦИКЛА: if(!found) { действия которые когда не найдено }`

Comment: @Mike, попробовал так: https://jsfiddle.net/tjuzma39/ не работает

Comment: @arthru "ПОСЛЕ ЦИКЛА, Карл!"

Comment: Все получилось, спасибо )

Answer (score 2):

Естественно, для всех элементов массива с `id` не равными `id`, код выполнит `else`. 'Товар не найден!' надо выводить **после цикла** - если товар не найден.

Comment: так он завязывается в итерации на `e.id`, что ему выполнять после цикла?

Comment: @Invision - в `else` `e.id` не используется

Comment: принцип в том что у нас есть конкретный id товара и мы выводим этот кокретный товар, но когда у нас id какойто рандомный (в нашей базе его нет) то просто ничего не происходит, вот я и решил написать else но оно тогда постоянно пишет else даже если товар с таким id найден

Comment: @Igor, так на один и тот-же идентификатор ссылается, т.е результатом выполнения будет последний элемент в массиве

Comment: наша база от куда мы выдераем нужый нам товар по id выглядит таким образом:products = [ { name: бла бла, id: 1 } {name: бла бла, id: 2} ]

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
var foundProduct = null;

products.forEach(function(e) { 
    if(e.id ==  id) {
      foundProduct = e;
    }
});

if (foundProduct) {
    document.getElementById('product-name').innerHTML = foundProduct.name;
    document.getElementById('product-miniAbout').innerHTML = foundProduct.miniAbout;
    document.getElementById('product-about').innerHTML = foundProduct.about;
    document.getElementById('product-category').innerHTML = foundProduct.category;
    document.getElementById('product-id').innerHTML = foundProduct.id;
    document.getElementById('product-bigPicture').innerHTML = '<img src="'+ foundProduct.img +'" style="max-height: 450px;" alt="'+ foundProduct.miniAbout +'">';
    document.getElementById('product-picture').innerHTML = '<img src="'+ foundProduct.img +'" alt="'+ foundProduct.miniAbout +'">';
    document.getElementById('product-price').innerHTML = foundProduct.price + ' Грн.';
} else {
    document.getElementById('product-bigPicture').innerHTML = '<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/38/awhCbhLqRceCdjcPQUnn_IMG_0249.jpg?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&w=1080&fit=max&s=9c2c8df6c036962d2ba24fd6af421a40" style="max-height: 450px;">';
    document.getElementById('product-about').innerHTML = 'Товар не найден!';
    document.getElementById('product-product').innerHTML = '<b>Cheap Shopping</b>';
    document.getElementById('delivery').innerHTML = '<b>Cheap Shopping</b>';
 }
```

Суть

1. выводите результат действия вы в одни и те же элементы
2. как следствие - если в массиве три элемента с id = 1,2,3, а ищите вы второй, то после прохождения второго и успешного if e.id == id будет следующая итерация, которая не отменяется словом return

Пример отмены нашёл в инете:

```
var BreakException= {};

try {
    [1,2,3].forEach(function(el) {
        if(el === 1) throw BreakException;
    });
} catch(e) {
    if (e!==BreakException) throw e;
}
```

Comment: e -> foundProduct

Comment: @Igor, спасибо, правлю

Answer (score 0):

В ES2015 у массивом есть метод [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), с ним код будет выглядеть проще

```
var product = products.find(function(el){return e.id == id; });
if(product) {
    document.getElementById('product-name').innerHTML = product.name;
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

А так же для поиска всегда можно использовать обычный `for`

```
var product;
for(var i=0;i<products.length;i++){
    if(products[i].id == id){
        product = products[i];
        break;
    }
}

if(product) {
    document.getElementById('product-name').innerHTML = product.name;
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```